# Google OAuth2Client.getToken() returns undefined in production but works locally

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

When running the following code locally, everything works well, and the refresh token is received from the authenticate() function.

```
const redirectUri = process.env.GOOG_REDIRECT_URI
constructor({clientId, secret}) {
    this.oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientId, secret, redirectUri);
}

async authenticate(code) {
  const {
     res: {
         data: { access_token, refresh_token },
     },
  } = await this.oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
  this.accessToken = access_token
  this.refreshToken = refresh_token
  return refresh_token //<-- refresh token is defined locally, not in production
}
```

When the same code is deployed to production, the same function returns undefined.

I double checked that the callback returns the correct payload in production also and it does. Here is how I handle callback.

```
const processGoogleOAuthCallback = async (req, res) => {
   try {
    const { state, code } = req.query; // <-- both state and code are well received when running both locally and in production.

    const googleClient = new GoogleClient({ clientId, secret })
    const refreshToken = await googleClient.authenticate(code) // undefined only in production, works locally
}
```

**Other notes**
As Google has a hard time verifying oAuth consent screens my suspicion is that it may be to do with that. Although, that being said, this is a pre-production project with 1 user (me) so by Google's standards, the verification is not really needed (I am doing it for future sake, and because it usually takes google multiple months to verify so I am starting early).

I am confused why this doesn't work in production and what am I doing wrong. Any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this? I tried creating an organization and switching my app to internal thinking that may have been preventing my oauth2client.setcredentials initialization but that didn't work and now i'm stuck again... and to add the code works locally.

Comment: Ureka! For my case i'm running my main container with a sidecar nodejs backen container, I failed to properly update the sidecar container to reflect my latest changes. The thought just came to me after I commented and after I spent a while creating a workspace and migrating the project to my organization, but hey at least I have that setup now, hope it will come in handy.